# Is it possible to add InAppBilling functionality to a free app we published before?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

First of all please excuse my ignorance. This question probably have a very clear answer though I just couldn't find it. Don't think that I didn't search for it. I actually look at the web and I tried to find the answer under InAppPurchase topic here on StackOverFlow. However, I am still lost.

Here what I am trying to understand, I know we can not sell a free app after we published it as a Free Application. But what if we publish it as Free with some advertisements then after some weeks we want to add an option like REMOVE ADDS FOR 1.49$ button. So, I mean can we add InAppBilling option to an app which was once free with ads? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to android documentation there is no reason you cant do that, just set up a wallet account, create the new version of the app with the ability to disable the ads as an inapp billing option and off you go.

the only restrict on google play store is once you go free you cant charge money for it(on download it is).

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Implementation :: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html